# Using a global list variable in Golang. Receiving "Use of package list without selector"

Tags: go

I have a global linked list named rooms. It is going to store the names of all the rooms this user enters in. In my function create I am trying to reference this list named rooms. I instantiate the list in my main function. When I try to add an item to the list "rooms" I receive the error "Use of package list without selector".

I would like to be able to add a string to my list named rooms from within my create function.

---

```
package main

import (
    "net"
    "fmt"
    "bufio"
    "os"
    "container/list"
)

var rooms list

func create() string{
    reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
    fmt.Print("Name the Chatroom");
    input, _ := reader.ReadString('\n');
    _ = rooms.PushFront(input);
    return "Joined room " + input;
}   

func main() {

    rooms := list.New()
    reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
    fmt.Print("Enter a name")
    name, _ := reader.ReadString('\n')

    // connect to this socket
    conn, _ := net.Dial("tcp", "127.0.0.1:8081")
    for { 
        // read in input from stdin
        reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
        fmt.Print("Text to send: ")
        text, _ := reader.ReadString('\n')
        // send to socket
        fmt.Fprintf(conn, text + "\n")
        // listen for reply
        message, _ := bufio.NewReader(conn).ReadString('\n')
        fmt.Print("Message from server: "+message)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type for rooms should be `*list.List`, a pointer to `List` type from package `list`.

Change `var rooms list` to `var rooms *list.List`

Comment: Also, do you know how to make conn a global variable?

Comment: Don't use the comments for new questions - ask a new question. But make sure you do some research first. : )

Comment: @Jacob - I hope my comment didn't come off as dismissive. Looking at it now, it seems like it could have. If we hash out your new question here, it won't be available for others who may have the same question in the future, and won't attract the attention of people best suited to answer it. I hope you've figured it out, though!

Comment: `var conn net.Conn` in the global scope (before/after `var rooms *list.List`)

Answer (score 2):

Play here https://play.golang.org/p/ORa6MI-2Pbn

Change `var rooms list` to `var rooms = list.New()`

Error because `var rooms list` is wrong: `list` is pkg name, you should write like this `*list.List`

Comment: I receive the error `prog.go:12:13: undefined: lists` if I Change `var rooms list` to `var rooms = list.New()`

Comment: @Jacob, I believe your issue is clear in the error. It said _lists_, with an "s".